# error: ext4_allocate_best_fit_partial: failed to allocate 3967 blocks, out of space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ext4, android

I am trying to build system.img from a folder which contains system files(extracted from system.img)

the system.img is for Api level 25 on emulator( Android SDK)

I am trying to run this command

```
sudo make_ext4fs -L system -l 274783648 -a system new_system.img savedir/
```

but I get this error

```
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 274780160
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 5600
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1048
    Label: system
    Blocks: 67085
    Block groups: 3
    Reserved block group size: 23
error: ext4_allocate_best_fit_partial: failed to allocate 3967 blocks, out of space?
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `df -h` and `df -hi` here? (The error says out of disk space)

Answer (score 1):

The error was related to the size of the image I was trying to create which was smaller than the folder size.

Increasing the size removed the error